# Problem understanding the make utility and the header .h files usage

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to learn the `make` command but I am having a little trouble with the way headers are being used

I got `prg1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
     printf("Hello World\n");
     print();
}
```

and the `prg2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
print()
{
     printf("Hello World from prg2\n");
}
```

and here is the make file

```
objects = prg1.o prg2.o

exe : $(objects)
    cc -o exe $(objects)

prg1.o : prg1.c
    cc -c prg1.c 

prg2.o : prg2.c
    cc -c prg2.c
```

This works perfectly.  But if I don't include `stdio.h` in both file and then I have to compile it using the `make`, how am I supposed to write the makefile?

Comment: Of all of the questions that one _could_ ask with respect to header files and `make`, it being a fairly knotty subject, this is one of the ones that makes very little sense.  Your C code is bad, by the way, and a standards-conformant C1999 or C2011 compiler will throw it out.  If you are using a C programming tutorial that teaches you implicit `int` and implicit function declarations from the start, then find a better one.  This is not the WWW site for doing so, however.  It's not even the WWW site for generic programming questions that are not specific to Unix and Linux.

Comment: Still, my question is how to handle inclusion of Header using make ?

Comment: You should include a header (`stdio.h` or any other) in every `.c` file that calls any functions from that header. The compiler expects you to and has no other way of santity-checking your function calls. Every `.c` file is compiled separately, whether you compile it with `make` or not. `make` has nothing to do with the right way to code a C source file.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I don't why my senior doesn't believe that every .C has to include it's .h at the beginning of the .C file. He wants me to compile a .C file & it's respective .H file by providing .H file in the command line. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I see. Your senior wants you to find out how GCC can *pre-include*
a header file. In that case the 2nd solution in @Kaz's answer
is the one you want. But understand that in practice the use of
the `-include` option is to force inclusion of some header file
that a project requires to be included *before any other* in
every file compiled for the project. It is a specialized feature,
not a normal way of including headers. And again, it is just a `gcc`
option, unconnected with `make`.

Comment: @MikeKinghan last quick question. Does it have any advantage over the normal procedure?

Comment: `-include <header>` causes the compiler to include the named header file
*before any other* in the compilation. That is an "advantage" if you *need*
that behaviour; otherwise not. It has the disadvantage that somebody
reading the source code *cannot see* that this header is included, which
will probably confuse them. So use this feature only when you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't include `<stdio.h>`, then you can do one of two things:

- supply a correct declaration for `printf` yourself:

  ```
  int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
  ```

  There is almost never any reason to do such a thing.
- If your compiler is GCC, use the `-include` compiler option to force the inclusion of `"stdio.h"`:

  ```
  prg1.o: prg1.c
          gcc -c -include stdio.h prg1.c
  ```

  This is completely hokey; don't do it.

Note that the `make` utility has nothing to do with ensuring that the correct header material is included in C translation units. `make` is a utility which runs shell commands in response to some files not existing or having modification stamps older than other files.